# Gatsby/React: how to create clean fallback for non JS users?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, gatsby

I want my site to work smoothly for users regardless if they have JS disabled or not. Right now I'm having a minor issue with a loading spinner. I don't want the spinner to show to non JS users. I want JS users to see the spinner immediately after initial render of the page.

Here's what I've tried so far:

**Approach 1:**

Make the spinner hidden by default. Make it visible in `componentDidMount`. This works, but when I simulate a user who is on a slow 3G network, it takes ~10 seconds for the component to mount (due to JS load time). It would be nice to get this number down to ~0.

**Approach 2:**

Make the spinner hidden by default. Use inline JS to make it visible after first render:

`document.getElementById('hasJavaScript').style.display = 'block';`

This doesn't work. I can put `<script>` tags inside JSX, but after Gatsby has compiled my page, I just see a console error for incorrect HTML. I can see this in the compiled HTML:

`<script type="text/javascript" class="jsx-1809226535">document.getElementById(&quot;spinner&quot;).style.display = &quot;block&quot;;</script>`

**Approach 3:**

Make the spinner visible by default. Use inline `<noscript>` tags to make it hidden. This has the same problem as approach 2, and some additional problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work with `<noscript>` tags by avoiding quotes in my CSS definitions.

```
<noscript>
    <style> 
        {`.spinner { display: none !important; }`}
    </style>
</noscript>
```